# Given an array $a$, we have to find product of $a_{j}$-$a_{i}$ modulo $998244353$ over all $i$ and $j$ given $j>i$

Tags: polynomials, fast-fourier-transform

Given an array $a$, we have to find product of $a_{j}$-$a_{i}$ modulo $998244353$ over all $i$ and $j$ given $j>i$. 
For eg. Let the array be $1,2,3$ then my answer will be calculated as-
$(2-1)$.$(3-1)$.$(3-2)$=$2$
As number of elements in the array could be large (upto $10^5$) I am looking for solution of order $nlogn$.
I have tried representing array as a polynomial but could get anything out of it.
Please help.

Comment: To get an idea, start by computing (a+b+c)(a+b+c).

Comment: I don't think it will help as I want product of difference and not sum in the array.

Comment: Can you credit the original source where you encountered this task?

Comment: @ViplawSrivastava Oops, sorry, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product $$V=\prod_{i<j}(a_j-a_i)$$ is the determinant of the [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) of the numbers $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$.

The square of this number is the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant)  $D$ of the polynomial $$p(x)=\prod_i(x-a_i)$$

This in turn is equal to $$V^2=D=(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}\prod_ip'(a_i)$$

You can quickly compute the coefficients of $p(x)$ and thus $p'(x)$, evaluate it at the $n$ points $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ and their product. Then compute square root. The sign of $V$ you determine by sorting and counting the parity of the number of switches.

You can do all this in $O(n\log^2(n))$.

See the relevant algorithms [here](http://www.orcca.on.ca/%7Eyxie/courses/cs2210b-2011/htmls/extra/fmv.pdf).

For the modular square root, you can use [Tonelli-Shanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm) for efficiency. Although the theoretic order of this step is constant since the prime $998244353$ is fixed.

Comment: @ViplawSrivastava FFT does that. A book that has the algorithms for all these steps is Aho, Hopcroft,Ullman *The design and analysis of computer algorithms*. For lack of a book, it seems that that particular step is mentioned [here](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1608/1608.01357.pdf).